# Logs starting "ipsec start" command

Tags: logs, strongswan

I am trying to take the Mobile IPv6 HOWTO (https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/HomeAgentSetup) as an example of configuration but when I run the "ipsec start" command I have just one line as an output (Starting strongSwan 5.7.1 IPsec [starter] ...) then it doesn't show anything else how is shown in the Mobile IPv6 HOWTO (logs informing about the access to some directories to take some files like loading ca certificates). If I can't see these logs I can't know if it works well or not. I thought maybe the log info it isn't shown in the 5.7.1 version but I'm not sure because I have used all the information that I found in the tutorials in this page but I don't know what is the reason.
(I am using Debian 9)

Comment: Thank you ! I founded the logs I needed there !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian systems the IPSec strongSwan logs can be found in `/var/log/syslog`.